# Dropdown Bootstrap is not working on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a theme with Wordpress and Bootstrap and have included their 'dropdown' for a filtering element on the page. It works fine in all browsers, including when I scale them down to mobile size. But, when I visit the site from an iPhone or iPad the dropdown doesn't drop down, so to speak.

This is the markup that I have:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="bdo-employee-filter dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-toggle filter-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <div class="text">Filtrera</div>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/">Rensa filtrering</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">IT</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Office of World Reign</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried following [Bootstrap's example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) and can't really see what could be wrong. Nothing happens at all when I try to open the dropdown from an iphone or ipad. On the same page I use their [navbar dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), and that works fine on all devices.

Comment: May be a conflict with other JS code on your page or incorrect HTML. Can you see any errors in your console? Your snippet works fine on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/110595). Open the [rendered page](http://www.bootply.com/render/110595) in an iPhone or iPad - it works for me on Safari on iOS7.

Comment: There's nothing in the console and when I open the page you linked to, it also works. So there must be something else wrong with my markup, I just can't find it!
The actual page is here: http://bdo.se.loopiadns.com/kontakt/medarbetare/ and it's the "Filtrera"-button to the right